# Ubuntu 14.04 not booting on main user after name change

Tags: 14.04, login, users, passwd-file

So I wanted to change the name of the home folder, and did so using the mv command: 
`mv /home/oldname /home/newname`. It worked fine. No errors appeared until I tried accessing the home folder. It said it couldn't find /home/oldname (I don't remember the full error).

I though I could fix it easily by editing the passwd file. I searched for passwd within the /etc directory and found a few results. I just double clicked the first result (I know it's stupid) and then the file explorer exited. I couldn't click on anything and nothing was working, so I rebooted the computer. When I came to the login screen, I entered my password and pressed enter. The screen went black for a while, and then returned to the login screen. Basically I can't login my main account, I can only use Guest, which deletes any changes to Ubuntu on exit. If anyone knows how I can edit the passwd file from there or fix it in another way, that'd be great. I know this might be a duplicate, but non of the questions I found were using the same command as me which might make a difference. Also please note that I don't want to rein

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your initial guess was correct - you need to change the home directory entry in `/etc/passwd` file. That means you can either use `sudo vipw` or `sudo sed -i 's;/home/oldName;/home/newName;' /etc/passwd` in terminal. To access virtual terminal press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F2</kbd> (or any F key from 1 to 6), and login there.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked! And on top of that, I get to keep the name change too!

Comment: I didn't know about `vipw`...

Comment: @Fabby I didn't know either until muru taught me :) he's all about vim